# What is the correct way to convert a std::unique_ptr to a std::unique_ptr to a superclass?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a class called `foo` which inherits from a class called `bar`.

I have a `std::unique_ptr` to an instance of `foo` and I want to pass it to a function that only takes `std::unique_ptr<bar>`. How can I convert the pointer so it works in my function?

Comment: Is `foo` a polymorphic instance ?

Comment: Make any functions which don't concern themselves with where the memory came from or what happens afterwards, take the parameters by reference (or raw pointer if it may be null).

Comment: @NeilKirk: This work for function, but it is a reasonable use case to store `unique_ptr<Base>` in a collection. And if the function has to store it...

Comment: `unique_ptr` has no copy constructor, so a function `f(std::unique_prt<T> p)` cannot be called without `std::move`. Perhaps you meant that your function takes a rvalue or lvalue reference?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can convert a `std::unique_ptr<foo>` rvalue to an `std::unique_ptr<bar>`:

```
std::unique_ptr<foo> f(new foo);
std::unique_ptr<bar> b(std::move(f));
```

Obviously, the pointer will be owned by `b` and if `b` gets destroyed `bar` needs to have a `virtual` destructor.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing special is required because of the inheritance.  You need to use `std::move` to pass the unique_ptr to a function, but this is true even if the types match:

```
#include <memory>

struct A {
};

struct B : A {
};

static void f(std::unique_ptr<A>)
{
}

int main(int,char**)
{
  std::unique_ptr<B> b_ptr(new B);
  f(std::move(b_ptr));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this syntax:

```
std::unique_ptr<parent> parentptr = std::unique_ptr<child>(childptr);
```

Or you may use `std::move`.

The other option is to emit raw pointer, but you need to change a function:

```
void func(const parent* ptr)
{
  // actions...
}
func(*childptr);
```

Here is a good article about smart pointers and passing it to functions: http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters.

Answer (score -1):

You can't, because it would violate the most basic `unique_ptr` rule: there has to be only one instance that holds a given pointer, and the `unique_ptr` has full ownership of it (when it goes out of scope, the pointee is deleted).

`unique_ptr<T>` and `unique_ptr<U>` (where `U : T`) aren't compatible, as you've seen.

For `shared_ptr`, for which you can have multiple instances, there is `std::static_pointer_cast` that behaves just like a `static_cast`, except that it accepts a `shared_ptr` and returns another one (and both point to the same object).

If you absolutely need to use a `unique_ptr`, you'll have to create a function that first disowns your current `unique_ptr` and puts that pointer into a new one of the right type. You might also need to do the opposite conversion after your function call.

Comment: +1. for completeness, `std::dynamic_pointer_cast<>` and `std::const_pointer_cast<>` exist for other common pointer conversions.

Comment: Of course you can, you just have to transfer ownership though, obviously.

Comment: @MatthieuM. "If you absolutely need to use a unique_ptr, you'll have to create a function that first disowns your current unique_ptr and puts that pointer into a new one of the right type." My point was that a `unique_ptr<T>` cannot bind to a `unique_ptr<U>` reference. Transferring ownership just like that is also not exception-safe.

Comment: @zneak: just like what ? `base.reset(derived.release())` is exception-safe (apart in VS...), `base = std::move(derived)` is exception-safe too (and more idiomatic). And I don't quite see why you would create a function to do that since it's so short to write.

Comment: @MatthieuM. It's not exception safe if you need to return the pointer to the original object so it lives its correct lifetime; and I believe there are no guarantees that this will be possible, since that object was moved into another one and it's not required to do anything except be destructible at this point (though it practice it would probably work, but the operation would still not be exception-safe if the callee threw).

Comment: @zneak: I have been reading your comment twice and I am afraid I still don't understand what you are trying to say :'( If you could help me out with example code illustrating the issue, I would be grateful.

Comment: @zneak: the comment is wrong, main possibly gave up its ownership when it passed it off by reference. It could be happen with anything, it could even happen with a pointer passed by reference. Once you pass something by reference, you just cannot assume its state did not change. I don't see what's peculiar to transfer of ownership here. Google Style Guide argues that it is why you should always pass by pointer (to make it a bit more obvious at call site), but it's like this in pretty much every language that embraces mutability....

Comment: @MatthieuM. I'm not saying it's technically impossible (it clearly is not). I'm saying it's not exception-safe. I hope the comment didn't obscure that.

Comment: @zneak: and I disagree, though it is a matter of qualification. `unique_ptr` provides the **Basic Exception Guarantee**, even for transfer of ownership, and thus is exception-safe. That the code **you** crafted does not provide the **Strong Exception Guarantee** (as it seems you would like) is a problem with your code.

Comment: @zneak "a function that first disowns your current... etc" ... you mean like the `unique_ptr` move-constructor? Which is a core part of what makes `unique_ptr` useful? This whole answer sounds like you don't actually understand `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Also, "My point was that a `unique_ptr<T>` cannot bind to a `unique_ptr<U>` reference." -- Okay, but the original question does **not** mention references.

Comment: @KyleStrand, there's no code example anywhere and interpretation is up to mind reading. Value conversions usually keep the original intact but it is not the case with unique_ptr.

Comment: @zneak Your answer is the only one that assumed an interpretation that (in your own words) "would violate the most basic `unique_ptr` rule." It's hardly "mind reading" to prefer a sensible interpretation to a nonsensical one.

Comment: @KyleStrand, what do you hope to get from this exchange?